# How to modify \textcite and its \finalnamedelim?

Tags: biblatex, citing, delimiters

When I cite with `\textcites` I would like to get as result as described with "Status desideratus":

[image]

Thats the MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents,babel}
\usepackage[           
backend=biber,
style=archaeologie,
inreferences,
lstabbrv,
lstlocations,
lstpublishers,
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{archaeologie-examples.bib}
%\renewcommand{\textcitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}%
  {\boolfalse{cbx:yearinparens}%  
  \usebibmacro{prenote}%
  }%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \renewcommand*\multinamedelim{\addcomma\space}%
  \renewcommand*\finalnamedelim{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
     \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}%
   \iffirstcitekey%
    {\setcounter{textcitetotal}{1}}%
    {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
     \multinamedelim}%
   \ifbool{cbx:seenote}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:seenote}}%
     {\usebibmacro{textcite}}}%
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}%
   {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:yearinparens}}%
   {}}%
  {\ifbool{cbx:seenote}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}}
%
 \DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}{\textcite}{}

\begin{document}
Status quo: \textcites[12]{Mann2011}[23]{Arnolds2005}\par
Status desideratus: Mann (2011, 12) und Arnolds (2005, 23)\par\bigskip
Status quo: \textcites[12]{Mann2011}[23]{Arnolds2005}[34]{Emme2013}\par
Status desideratus: Mann (2011, 12), Arnolds (2005, 23) und Emme (2013, 34)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on here.

Firstly, `biblatex.def` has this interesting section in it:

```
% This is a provisional definition for \iffinalcitedelim{<true>}{<false>}, a
% test that should expand <true> if the next non-compact citation delimiter
% is the last one in the citation list printed by \textcite or \textcites.
\newcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}{\@secondoftwo}
```

We can make this test actually do something useful:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}{%
  \iflastcitekey
    {\@firstoftwo}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
\makeatother
```

Secondly, I notice that you've changed the definition of the `\textcite` command from the default in `archaeologie.cbx`. Among other things, you've replaced `\textcitedelim` with `multinamedelim`, which I think is not what you want.

I'll leave it to you to decide exactly how much of this macro you need to change, but it will give the output you want without changing it at all. Although due to a bug in the macro, also present in your question (it contains `cbx:parens` instead of `cbxyearinparens`), it only works for `\textcites`, not `\textcite`.

Here's a full example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents,babel}
\usepackage[           
backend=biber,
style=archaeologie,
inreferences,
lstabbrv,
lstlocations,
lstpublishers,
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{archaeologie-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}{%
  \iflastcitekey
    {\@firstoftwo}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}{\textcite}{}

\begin{document}
Status quo: \textcites[12]{Mann2011}[23]{Arnolds2005}\par
Status desideratus: Mann (2011, 12) und Arnolds (2005, 23)\par\bigskip
Status quo: \textcites[12]{Mann2011}[23]{Arnolds2005}[34]{Emme2013}\par
Status desideratus: Mann (2011, 12), Arnolds (2005, 23) und Emme (2013, 34)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}{\iflastcitekey}` is shorter and equivalent. Note that a few comp/ibid styles have different definitions, but `\iflastcitekey` seems to be good here.